# How does a map() function work over an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, filter, map-function

The definition in my book is the method passes each element of the array on which it is invoked to the function you specify, and returns a new array containing the value returned by that function.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.map(function(x) { return x*x; }); // b is [1,4,9]
```

I would want the function to only return 1 if 4 is not found.

The case would be

```
var bool = false;
a.map(function(x) {

if (x == 4){
  bool = true;
}

return x;
}).filter(function(x) {if( (x == 1) && ( bool = true)){ return null}});
```

The way I would like to use it is by iterating over an array and than dynamically change the map at the end. How would I do that?

My problem now is with strings, so 
Here is another case, where 1 is now called unknown. And if anything after "unknown" is found, remove "unknown" from the list before joining.

```
 var wordList = [];
    var newSource = false;
    str = results[i].Meaning.map(function(m){
        count++;

        if ((!m.Source && !contains(wordList, "unknown"))) {
            wordList[count] = "unknown";
            return "unknown";
            }
        if (!m.Source ) {
            return m.Source;
        }

            if ( contains(wordList, "unknown") ) {
                newSource = true;
            }
            if (!contains(wordList, m.Source) ) {
                wordList[count] = m.Source;
                return m.Source;
            }

    }).filter(function(x) { return x  }).filter(function(x){
        if (newSource == true ) { return (x != "unknown")}}).join(', ');
```

Comment: You didn't include a `return` in the map function.

Comment: For questions like that I suggest to always take a look at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: It sounds like you just want `a.indexOf(4) >= 0`.  I don't see a reason to use `.map()` here.

Comment: That is a general case, usually there will be many conditions inside the map. The one that is being annoying is dynamically changing the contents.

Comment: It is just not clear what problem you're trying to solve.  You have an input array, but it is not clear what you want the final output to be.  Please show both input and desired output and I'm sure folks here can help you select the best way to get there, but you have to show the desired result.

Comment: Just updated, in the real time problem. I was looking for more help on seeing the values of map() as they are being evaluated so you can delete the list before having to filter them at the end. What variable shows the array in the map?

Comment: Dude, if you need to do condense a value from a collection, in your case, that operation is called reduce... map is only preparation for the final "scalar" value...

Comment: That makes sense. So change the .filter() to .reduce(if newSource == true...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the first function:

```
function f1(x) {
  var bool = false;

  if (x == 4){
    bool = true; 
  }

  return x;
}
```

This function changes the variable `bool` locally, and returns `x`. So, no matter what happens to `bool`, this function is equivalent to the *identity* function:

```
function(x) { return x; }
```

Because `.map(f)` returns an array with `f` applied to all elements, we have that `a.map(f1)` is equivalent to `a.map(identity function)` which is equivalent to `a`.

The second function is inside the filter:

```
if( (x == 1) && ( bool = true)) return null;
```

We have some issues here:

- There's no `function(x)` signature
- You are trying to access the `bool` variable, that was declared on the first function.

I suggest whenever you use `map` and `filter`, that you use *pure* functions, which means your function just process the parameter passed to them, and return the result.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the first problem; please give more details and I'll try to help you with a solution.

Look for tutorials in map, filter and reduce on Google. For example, [this egghead video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-chaining-the-array-map-and-filter-methods).

Comment: Thank you for the help and link. I fixed the edits by the way.

Comment: Much better now, @collegeWaldo . But, I'm still having a problem understanding what you want with your second algorithm. Could you please give some examples of inputs and outputs on your question, so I could help you with a solution?

Comment: Yes will reply within 24 hours.